# How can I set my wired Xbox controller to player 2?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I got a wired Xbox controller and I connected it with joytokey it's controlling Isaac (Player 1) instead of joining as Player 2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

That may be in issue because you're using JoytoKey. 
I have a wireless Xbox controller, and I plugged it in, and it worked just fine with Rebirth. I didn't have to do any fiddling at all with JoytoKey or xPadder or anything.